# Bad substitution on raspi does not occur on mac

Tags: macos, bash, shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to write a script that replaces spaces with underscores in every file in a given directory. I have a shell script that works on my mac, however when I move it to my pi it throws the error: remove-spaces.sh: 3: remove-spaces.sh: Bad substitution. I'm wondering how I can get rid of this error and what is causing it. Script below.

```
for f in $1/*.*;
    do mv "$f" "${f// /_}";
done
```

Comment: `/bin/sh` on your pi probably doesn't support the `//` expansion. Try explicitly using `/bin/bash` if you have it. Otherwise try using `tr` in a sub-shell instead.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I'm pretty new to bash scripts.

Comment: `"$(tr ' ' _ <<<"$f")"` or so.

Comment: If `/bin/sh` doesn't support `${//}`, it's not likely to support a herestring!  Try `mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | tr ' ' _)"`

Comment: Thanks Will, that worked perfectly.